# Pass column value in a function using inner join-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using below query which has a user defined function udf2PositionStateAsOf and it takes one parameter value and i want to join this function with a table and want to pass its field value "PK_positionMaster" as parameter of the function. but it throws the error The multi-part identifier "PM.PK_positionMaster" could not be bound. Please provide your suggestion to solve this

```
SELECT *, PM.PK_positionMaster
FROM [dbo].[udf2PositionStateAsOf](PM.PK_positionMaster) UDF inner join
     PositionMaster PM
     ON UDF.PK_positionMaster = PM.PK_positionMaster
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `cross apply`:

```
SELECT UDF.*, PM.PK_positionMaster
FROM PositionMaster PM CROSS APPLY
     [dbo].[udf2PositionStateAsOf](PM.PK_positionMaster) UDF
```